# Java. Spring. TomCat

Tags: java, spring

Пишу Spring-Web-MVC приложение.

В идее настроил deploy:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

при запуске, вижу, что все корректно создалось:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И в целом все хорошо работает кроме вот этого метода:

```
public Class<?> getClazz(String event) {

        Class<?> eventClass = null;

        if (event != null) {
            try {
                eventClass = Class.forName(event);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error(e.toString());
            }
        }
        return eventClass;
    }
```

Когда я пытаюсь найти класс ONAPPINSTALL, Class.forName(event) выдает - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ONAPPINSTALL

Как понять где Class.forName(event) ищет, что не находит? и как ему указать правильное место для поиска???

Comment: ищет в classpath. Убедитесь что данный класс у вас попадает в билд

Comment: А если это не класс, то проверьте, что вы передаете в данный метод

Comment: вот я второй скрин приложил, где как раз виден ONAPPINSTALL.class - я так понимаю, это и есть попадание в билд?

Comment: а где настраивается classpath?

Comment: В тесте ошибку допустил... вставлял "ONAPPINSTALL" вместо "ru.bityard.bitrix24.serverAuth.bitrixEvents.ONAPPINSTALL" - 2 часа потерянного времени на рабочем коде )))